# Help with writing a .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ive seen alot of .htaccess tuts and none of them seem to make sense. All I want to do is rename my www.example.com/index.php to www.example.com/home

All of these tuts give horrible examples and this is what I have so far. Dont be suprised if it looks bad, I think it does too but idk where to find a decent tut on how to write a correct one

My question was, how would I write a .htaccess file that would successfully rename my index.php to home

This is seriously all I have so far

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be all you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L,QSA]
# Rewrite imaginary otherpage to someplace.php...
RewriteRule ^otherpage$ someplace.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^adifferentpage$ someplace_else.php [L,QSA]
```

Now requests to `/home` are silently served index.php. Any additional parameters in the querystring are passed in as well.

Comment: Could I rewrite multiple .php files in the same htaccess file?

Comment: @Marlo Stanfield Absolutely.  Add as many `RewriteRule` directives as you need. I'll add some examples.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like a charm